# Solving awkward quadratic equation to obtain "nice" solution.

Tags: problem-solving, quadratics

I would like to solve the following quadratic equation to get a "nice" analytic solution for $\rho$.

$\rho^2(r\sin\theta-2nr^2)+\rho(2nr^3-2r^2\sin\theta-2\sin\theta+2nr)-2nr^2+3r\sin\theta=0$

where $r=1-\cos\theta$ (I cannot see how this could be used to simplify the quadratic equation.)

I would hope that the solution to be found which be of a simple form as that would correspond nicely to the larger problem I am working on.

Also $\theta=\pi/n$

EDIT: I would hope that the solution $\displaystyle \rho=1-\frac{sin(\frac{\pi}{n})}{n}$ would be one of the solutions to the quadratic.

Comment: I would hope for some cancelling in the solution

Comment: Would small angle approximation ($r \approx \theta^2/2$ and $sin(\theta) \approx \theta)$ work in the context of your problem?

Comment: Sadly not. My larger problem concerns chaotic billiard dynamics

Comment: One sort-of nice thing about $r=1-\cos\theta$ is that it's also equal to $2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$. That may be easier to juggle.

Comment: @Semiclassical even better, put everything into half-angle form, it helps a bit. Having both $r$ and $\sin \theta$ makes it impossible to group them correctly.

Comment: Is there a place on stack exchange where people could look at my notes to see if they can move the larger problem forward? Thing is it wouldn't be able to be phrased as a question and otherwise would probably be downvoted.

Comment: Let $\displaystyle\;z = \frac{\sin\theta}{2nr - 2\sin\theta}\;$, we can rewrite the equation as

$$\rho^2 (1 + z) - \rho (r+1/r) +  (1-z) = 0$$

The two roots have the form:
$$\rho_{\pm} = \frac{r + 1/r \pm \sqrt{ (r+1/r)^2 - 4(1-z^2)}}{2(1+z)}
= \frac{r + 1/r \pm \sqrt{ (r-1/r)^2 + 4z^2}}{2(1+z)}
$$
Let $t = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}$, we have:

$$r = 1 - \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} = \frac{2t^2}{1+t^2}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
z = \frac{\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}{2n\frac{2t^2}{1+t^2} - \frac{4t}{1+t^2}}
= \frac{1}{2(nt-1)}$$ Whether you consider the final expression in $t$ is simple is up to you.

Comment: If $\rho = 1-\sin(\pi/n)/n$ were a solution, then you would be able to substitute the value into the equation and get zero. However, what you get is a complicated relation involving $n$ and trigonometric functions of $\pi/n$. This relation may be true for *some* $n$, but it's not true for *all* $n$ (for instance, $n=1$ and $n=2$ already fail).

Comment: Good point. I dont think, in the context of my problem, that I care about the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ as they correspond to points and lines. I am concerned about $n \geq 3$.

Comment: The value $\rho = 1 - \sin(\pi/n)/n$ is not a root for $n=3$, $4$, $6$, $17$, $55$, or $123$, either. I'd be rather surprised if it were a root for any particular integer $n$.

Comment: You could post some of your notes about the larger problem as background for this question. (Just add it as an edit under the current stuff, perhaps with a `---` separator for clarity.) I'm sure most answerers would appreciate knowing the context of the equation, so that they can decide for themselves whether a "nice" solution is feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a particularly simple form.

Solution:

$\rho = (R \pm S)/Q$

Where

$Q = \textrm{ sin}( \frac{\pi}{2 n} )^3( 32 n - 16 \textrm{ cot}(\frac{\pi}{2 n}))$

$R = -12 \textrm{ cos}(\frac{\pi}{2 n}) + 6 \textrm{ cos}(\frac{3 \pi}{2 n} ) - 
  2 \textrm{ cos}(  \frac{5 \pi}{2 n}) + 
  2 n \left(14  \textrm{ sin}( \frac{\pi}{2 n}) - 5  \textrm{ sin}( \frac{3\pi}{2 n}) + 
      \textrm{ sin}( \frac{5\pi}{2 n}) \right)$

$S = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{22 - 58 n^2 + 6 (1 + 17 n^2) \textrm{ cos}( \frac{\pi}{n} ) - 
 56 n^2 \textrm{ cos}(\frac{2\pi}{n}) + (9 + 11 n^2) \textrm{ cos}(\frac{3\pi}{n}) + 
 2 (-3 + n^2) \textrm{ cos}(\frac{4\pi}{n}) - (-1 + n^2) \textrm{ cos}(\frac{5\pi}{n}) - 
 20 n  \textrm{ sin}( \frac{\pi}{n}) + 8 n \textrm{ sin}( \frac{2\pi}{n}) - 22 n \textrm{ sin}(\frac{3\pi}{n}) + 
 12 n \textrm{ sin}(  \frac{4\pi}{n} ) - 2 n \textrm{ sin}( \frac{5\pi}{n})} $

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is so easy as to solve it, it would be possible if we had the expression leading to this which is relatively simple and we could get simple closed expression,Anyways if you're asking for a solution:

---

Solving in wolfram alpha at ***[here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Crho%5E2((1-cos(%5Cpi%2Fn))%5Csin(%5Cpi%2Fn)-2n(1-cos(%5Cpi%2Fn))%5E2)%2B%5Crho(2n(1-cos(%5Cpi%2Fn))%5E3-2(1-cos(%5Cpi%2Fn))%5E2%5Csin(%5Cpi%2Fn)-2%5Csin(%5Cpi%2Fn)%2B2n(1-cos(%5Cpi%2Fn)))-2n(1-cos(%5Cpi%2Fn))%5E2%2B3(1-cos(%5Cpi%2Fn))%5Csin(%5Cpi%2Fn)%3D0&incParTime=true)*** I got the following two roots:

Let $$\cos(\lambda\pi/n)=c_{\lambda}$$ And similiarly $$\sin(\lambda\pi/n)=s_{\lambda}$$
Now let $$\color{red}{S_Q}=62n^2-106n^2c_1+72n^2c_2-37n^2c_3\\+10n^2c_4-n^2c_5-36ns_1+32ns_2-38ns_3\\+16ns_4-2ns_5+6c_1+9c_3+c_5+22$$
And
$$\color{red}{D_N}=-12ns_1+4ns_3+c_1-c_3$$
And
$$\color{red}{R_D}=-14ns_1+5ns_3-ns_5+6c_1-3c_3+c_5$$
Then roots are:
$$\rho_1=\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{2}\color{red}{D_N}}[\sqrt{\color{red}{S_Q}}-\color{red}{R_D}]$$